# Error parsing an XML with xinclude and xpointer

Tags: xml, xerces, xinclude

I'm using Jdom 2.0.5 and opening a document one.xml which includes another file two.xml through xinclude. I'm calling the builder as follows:

```
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    builder.setJDOMFactory(new LocatedJDOMFactory());
    builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/xinclude", true);
    Document doc = builder.build(new File("c:\\temp\\one.xml"));
    XMLOutputter out = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    System.out.println("salida es "+out.outputString(doc));
```

the file one.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<eco xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <tmp-path>/opt/eco/ecoprd/tmp</tmp-path>
    <!--
    <xi:include href="two.xml" parse="xml"/>
    -->
    <xi:include href="two.xml" parse="xml" xpointer="web-servers"/>
</eco>
```

and two.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<eco>
    <web-servers xml:id="web-servers">
        <valuations>
            <url-base>http://naboo:8080</url-base>
            <context>/Statements</context>
            <path>/services/ValuationsXMLGenerator</path>
        </valuations>
    </web-servers>
</eco>
```

the inclusion of the file without the xpointer works fine. But if I use xpointer, I get an error as follows:

```
org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 7 of document file:/c:/temp/one.xml: An 'include' failed, and no 'fallback' element was found.
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:228)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:277)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:264)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1116)
    at test.XMLTest.main(XMLTest.java:17)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/c:/temp/one.xml; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 65; An 'include' failed, and no 'fallback' element was found.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
    ... 4 more
```

What I'm missing? supposedly the xpointer="web-servers" should get the element web-serves with xml:id="web-servers", but it is not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xerces only supports the xpointer element() Scheme

- https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/xpointer/XPointerHandler.html
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-xptr-element-20030325/

so maybe

```
<xi:include href="two.xml" parse="xml" xpointer="element(web-servers)"/>
```

or

```
<xi:include href="two.xml" parse="xml" xpointer="element(/1/1)"/>
```

where the first /1 is the "eco" element
and the second /1 is the "web-servers" element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use xpointer, try using this: http://etourdot.github.io/xincproc/